# Solución error: no hay restricción unique que coincida con las columnas dadas en la tabla

Tags: postgresql

Este error me salió cuando trataba de crear una llave foránea mediante la interfaz gráfica postgresql v.10.10

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este error es común, En mi caso fue un error lógico. la solución es simple, pero en su momento me llevo un rato buscando la causa :v. y era sencillo, La llave foránea se debe crear en la tabla donde va a estar ubicada dicha llave y no al revés.

ejemplo: Tengo dos tablas relacionadas Producto y Categoría. La llave    foránea esta ubicada en la tabla Producto; por lo tanto, se debe crear la llave foránea en la tabla Producto (Yo lo estaba haciendo al revés creando la llave foránea en la tabla Categoría). El resultado es que se creo la llave y ya no me salio ese error.